# Ros launch command not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to auto launch a roslaunch file, whenever ubuntu starts.
I have written a shell command file "start.sh" and it contains "roslaunch pkg_name file.launch"
When i try to execute this shell file in terminal, it runs successfully.
But when it runs automatically on start up, the terminal shows "source not found", "roslaunch not found" . Can any one help me correct it.
the link to autostarting a sh file is : http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/auto-start-ROS-launch-script-on-boot-up-td1687093.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264704/ros-launch-command-not-found/) by [UsmanArif](https://answers.ros.org/users/27566/usmanarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-06-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If roslaunch isn't found it's likely that you have not done the first thing in the linked example script of sourcing the `setup.bash` file in your script. If you'd like more information please share a minimal reproduction of your script that doesn't work, using standard tools that will make it easy for us to reproduce.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [UsmanArif](https://answers.ros.org/users/27566/usmanarif/) on 2017-06-26**:
This is my shell file. Its works fine when i run ./start.sh in terminal, but not at startup.

#! /bin/sh
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source /home/ubuntu/guidance_ws/devel/setup.bash
echo "launching the launch file"
roslaunch rfly_launch main.launch

**Comment by [UsmanArif](https://answers.ros.org/users/27566/usmanarif/) on 2017-06-27**:
i found the problem. The sh file has to be run as a bash file. so by replacing first line (#! /bin/sh) by #! /bin/bash,  works